# Showing that every abelian group is metabelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, metabelian-groups

Some terms before I define my problem:

> **Definition:** A group is *abelian* if every pair of elements commutes.
>
> **Proposition:** All subgroups of an abelian group are normal.
>
> **Definition:** A group $G$ is called *metabelian* if it has an abelian normal subgroup $N$ such that $G/N$ is also an abelian group.

I am tasked with proving that every abelian group is metabelian, but I have no idea where to start. I am inclined to believe that I should prove that $G/N$ is abelian if $G$ is abelian and $N$ is a normal subgroup. This satisfies the definition of metabelian, and since $G$ and $N$ are arbitrary, shouldn’t that conclude the argument?

Comment: Not following.  Why can't you just take $N=\{e\}$?  All you need one "good" $N$, right?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that, to be honest. How would I use that to prove all abelian groups are metabelian?

Comment: Well...can you see that taking $N=\{e\}$ works for any abelian group $G$?  Alternatively, take $N=G$.  Same principle.

Comment: By the way, another standard definition is to say that $G$ is [metabelian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabelian_group), if it is $2$-step solvable, i.e., if $[G,G]$ is abelian. For an abelian group $G$ this is even more obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $G$ is abelian.

Each subgroup of an abelian group is both abelian and normal in the group; in particular, $G\unlhd G$.  Observe that $G/G$ is isomorphic to the trivial group, which is abelian.

Hence $G$ is metabelian.

Comment: And one could equally well take $N=\{e\}$ instead of $N=G$.